# How to count tables inside a cell of table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, count, html-table

I have some tables nested inside a cell table, I want to count how many table inside that cell with jQuery, is that possible?

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>birthday</th>
        <th>hoby</th>
        <th>country</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <table class="groupbycountry" id="spain">
                <thead> a row of col title  </thead>
                <tbody> rows of data</tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="groupbycountry" id="italy">
                <thead>a row of col title</thead>
                <tbody>rows of data </tbody>
            </table>
            //and many more table of country according the user input 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <table name="inputdata">
                <form name="myprofile">
                    //the input tag
                </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Is that possible to count tables `class=groupbycountry` inside that parent table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property which returnes the number of selected elements, try the following:

```
var len = $('table:eq(0) .groupbycountry').length
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfhrz/)

Comment: what if there is no class added inside table tag? can i write like this? $('table tbody').find('table');

Comment: @Ahok yes you can select them without class name

Comment: i've tried that, but the result is none.. i tried this too.. $('table tbody > table');

Comment: @Ahok because you are using `child` selector, your tables are children of td element. try this: `$('table:eq(0)').find('table').length`

Comment: aren't that script select table inside tfoot too?

Comment: if you want to select those that are in tbody you can try: `$('table:eq(0) tbody').find('table').length`

Answer (score 1):

You could do ->

```
var tCount = $('.groupbycountry').filter('table').length;
$('#tables').text('There are '+tCount+' tables.');
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/TcJDn/)